# How do I make my background images cover the entire screen on retina devices?

Tags: css, iphone, ipad, responsive-design, background

My jumbotron background images only take up about half of the browser’s height on high-res mobile devices (e.g. iPhone, iPad, etc.).
I want my background images to cover most (if not all) of the screen on high-res mobile devices.

http://nelsonforfresno.org/ - site that I’m trying to implement my images to

CSS code I’m using for the background images…

```
.donate-hero {
    background: #485563 url(../img/donate-bg.jpg) no-repeat center center;
    background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    height: 100%;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

set width and height of image like this

```
.donate-hero {
    background: #485563 url(../img/donate-bg.jpg) no-repeat center center;
    background-size: cover;
    -webkit-background-size: cover;
    -moz-background-size: cover;
    -o-background-size: cover;
    width:100wh;
    height:100vh;
}
```

Note: This will make the image take up all of of the browser's space if it is the only element on the page

Edit: see this link for further details on vh and wh measurements

http://thenewcode.com/660/Using-vw-and-vh-Measurements-In-Modern-Site-Design

Answer (score 0):

This meta tag did the trick for me. It helped me with instructing the browser to  scale down my entire web page to fit the screen, regardless of the device-pixel ratio associated with that device (i.e. iPhone, iPad, tablet, etc.).

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
```

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_viewport.asp